# Line print outputting device, capture, spool, and print to network

Tags: pdf, printer, printing, print-to-pdf, capture

I have several pieces of equipment with RS232 or LPT ports which print to old line print printers. One example is a Mictomeritcs density measurement machine which prints directly to a line printer(EPSON LQ 570+) via LPT port.

I would like to adapt from the device's LPT to USB and connect it to my computer, then have the output captured and stored in some file format, preference to pdf. Lastly, I would like to print to a network printer if needed. Any ideas out there?

Comment: The buzz words to describe your problem are: you want to **capture printer data**, similar to [these scenarios](http://printrecorder.com/), and then you want to use a **printer emulator** to convert that captured data to `.pdf` files.  Once you have `.pdf` files you can print those to a local or network printer; networking is not a salient aspect to your problem.